# Mechanize without a form, just textbox and button

Tags: python, html, mechanize

I've been searching Google for almost every query I can think of related to this. The page I'm trying to submit is something similar to this. There is no form. The objects are not grouped in a form. Most other threads talk about the form not having a name, but in my case, the page doesn't have a form at all.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <br/>
    <img id="imageXYZ" />
    <br/>
    <input id="inputXYZ" />
    <br/>
    <button id="submitObject">Go</button>
    <br/>
    <script type="text/javascript">blah blah blah</script>
</div>
```

So when there is no form, simply just an input field and button, how do I select a form so I can fill in the text box and click the button?

Thank-you so much!

Comment: If you found the solution to your original question you should answer it using the answer form instead if updating the question. Just a kind notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, I had to do 2 things to get this to work with the code above. First, I had to use this line of code to select all the objects without a form.

```
Br.form = Br.global_form()
```

Secondly, the HTML code is formatted wrong, so I had to add a parameter to my initial browser call:

```
Br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. Your answer helped me as well.